# Why does a JavaScript object's reference works but not the value?

Tags: javascript, pointers, linked-list, javascript-objects, pass-by-reference

I'm constructing a linked list in JavaScript by following a tutorial and below is a sample code snippet. This does successfully create a linked list but I'm having a hard time understanding how the 'test' function works here.

I want to understand the following

1. This works only when the newNode variable(A JS pointer) is assigned to 'tail.next' and 'tail'. I tried assigning the actual value of the newNode object to both 'tail' and 'tail.next' but it doesn't work.
2. 'tail = newNode' -> It appears that the tail is being overridden and that the connection between head and the tail has been broken. Yet, this works somehow.

I know this has something to do with pointers or pass-by-reference. Can someone please explain me what's really happening?

```js
let head = {
  value: 1,
  next: null
}

let tail = head;

const test = (num) => {
  let newNode = {
    value: num,
    next: null
  }

  tail.next = newNode;
  tail = newNode;
}

test(3);
console.log(head,tail)
test(6);
console.log(head,tail)
```

Comment: There is only one way for a JavaScript variable (or object property) to have an object as a value, and that is as a reference to the object.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "a JS pointer" or by "I tried assigning the actual object".  And I suspect you're over-thinking this, or in some way confusing the difference between an *object* and a *variable*.  `head` remains constant, and with each new addition to the list `tail` is assigned to that new addition.  So `head` has a `next` property which points to the next element, which has a `next` property which points to the next element, etc., etc. until the last object, which `tail` also references.

Comment: `I tried assigning the actual object`,  not sure what you mean here.  What's actual object?.

Comment: I tried to make you a snippet. Please update it to be a [mcve] with input and expected output

Comment: @David @Keith By actual object, I meant the 'newNode' object.
As in, instead of 
`tail.next = newNode;
tail = newNode;`

I tried with 
`tail.next = {
    value: num,
    next: null
  };
tail = {
    value: num,
    next: null
  };`

While the former works as expected, the latter however doesn't. And I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @GiridharanSelvaraju: Then what do you mean by a "pointer"?  How is the "actual object" different from the object you're showing in the code?  Is there some specific operation in the code shown which isn't doing what you expect?  **Edit:** The latter "doesn't work" because it creates two different objects instead of one.  So `tail.next` and `tail` refer to two different things.

Comment: Because then you have created 2 separate instances of the node your adding.  IOW: `tail.next` will be looking at a different instance that `tail` is looking at.   To put it simply `{}  !== {}`

Comment: @David Earlier, tail pointed to the head and I get that. But, later on the tail points to the 'newNode' object and when the `test` function is called the second time, it isn't pointing to head anymore. So, how does updating `tail.next` affect the `head` also in the second function call?

Comment: @GiridharanSelvaraju: You really do seem to be over-thinking this.  A lot.  When you do this: `tail.next = newNode;` - Whatever object `tail` currently references will have its `next` property updated to reference the object that `newNode` references.  Then when you do this: `tail = newNode;` - The `tail` variable will now reference the object that `newNode` references.  In the code shown, `head` is never re-assigned and always references the same object (the "first" object in the "list" of objects).  It's `next` property references the next object, which then references the next object, etc.

Comment: It seems like your question isn't really Javascript related, it might be best if you first read up on how Single Linked Lists work, this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singly-linked-list-definition-meaning-dsa/ seems to explain nicely.  Although Javascript doesn't use pointers, but reference types for object, they work pretty much the same way. eg.  If you say do -> `let a = {a: 1}; let b = a; b.b = 2; console.log(a); console.log(b);`  the output would be `{a:1, b:2}` for both `a` and `b` as there both pointing at the same object in memory.

Comment: @David @Keith 
I think I got it now.

Fn call #1
`tail.next = newNode` Since tail points to head here, the next property is updated on both head and tail.
`tail = newNode` This effectively means that tail is now pointing to `head.next` as they point to the same memory in location.

Fn call #2
`tail.next = newNode` Now, the tail's(head.next) next property is updated to the newNode and so on..
`tail = newNode` Now, the tail points to `head['next']['next']` and it goes on..

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @GiridharanSelvaraju: Sounds about right to me.  The term "pointer" that you've been using isn't entirely accurate, but "reference" is.  When it comes to an object (or an array, which is a specific kind of object), any variable/property/array-index/etc. which references that object can *linguistically* be thought of as "a pointer" to the object, in that it's just a reference and not the object itself, and that the referece can be re-directed to another object without affecting the first.  But "pointer" specifically is likely to be misleading in terminology.